# How to display the content only to the allowed IP address

Tags: php

```
    <?php  
        $allow = array("xxx.xx.xxx.xxx","xxx.xx.xxx.xxx"); //allowed IPs

        if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allow) && !in_array($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"], $allow))  {  ?>
            <div class="enclose comn-pg">
            <h1 align="center" style="padding:10% 0;">Access denied.  This page is accessible only to customers.</h1>
            </div>                  


        <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="enclose comn-pg">
            <div id="primary">
            <div id="content" role="main">

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

            <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            </div><!-- #content -->
            </div><!-- #primary -->
            </div>

        <?php
        }
    ?>
```

I tried with above code to dispaly the content only to the allowed IP address, but it is not working. Can anyone suggest me how to restrict the content?

Comment: What is not working? Have you debug properly ?

Comment: i don't know weather the code is correct or not what i am facing is after giving an allowed ip address i am not getting the secret content which i want to display only to the allowed ip address viewers. @ Laxmana

Comment: Are you using any caching plugins or software on the webserver? This code will not work with most caching mechanisms. It would work with an opcode cache, but not with any static or pagecache systems.

Comment: can you tell me what is wrong in the above code @  Laxmana

Comment: i did not used any cache plugins @ totels

Comment: @Laxmana you'll need to be a bit more clear, there doesn't appear to be any problem with the conditional.

PullataPraveen, a few dumb questions: 1. did you add your own IP to the allow list to test? 2. did you try outputting the values to see what is actually being compared?

Comment: Yeap i added my own ip address and even tried to output.. actually i have a content if the page is allowed it shows a content if is not allowed ip address then displays a meeesge that Access denied.
As i asked my friend's ip address and asked to see the page he was able to access that page only in one browser but was not able to access in other browsers...
 @totels

Comment: no idea how this question is even remotely related to wordpress. anyway blocking by IP address is usually a bad idea

Comment: I agree with Mark. Also notice that HTTP headers can be easily spoofed.

Comment: Ofcourse @Mark but sometime its need of making some pages only visible to the required persons,... any how thanks for the help. The above code is working perfectly. It might be useful for some other persons.. in future

Comment: @PullataPraveen, it works for a very weak definition of "works" on front end (API type of access is different thing) as user change IPs all the time and this kind of hardcoding is basically impossible to debug once they start to ask why can't they access their content. The proper thing to do is to go the long way and have user registration. Just saying for the benefit of whoever will have the same idea in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code and its working fine for me.

```
<?php  
    $allow = array("xxx.xx.xxx.xxx","xxx.xx.xxx.xxx"); //allowed IPs

    if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $allow) && !in_array($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"], $allow) && !in_array($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"], $allow))  {  ?>
        <div class="enclose comn-pg">
        <h1 align="center" style="padding:10% 0;">Access denied.  This page is accessible only to customers.</h1>
        </div>                  


    <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="enclose comn-pg">
        <div id="primary">
        <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

        <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #primary -->
        </div>

    <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Where to add the above code?? and as you said you have tried my code did you checked in all browsers?? @lalitpendharemd

Comment: this is a just example of your code. you can put this code in your template file.

Comment: The above code which you provided is not working showing a blank page..
@lalitpendhare

Comment: I think you doing something wrong. you need to put your code. I have updated my answer and put this into your template file.

Comment: Can you attach overall code here?? please so that i can check with that by copying the code

Comment: i copied your code and pasted in my template file the code is almost similar to the code which i have attched. the page is displaying only in one browser and in other browsers it is showing access denied.If you have tried then please cross check with all browsers

Comment: i have tried with different browser. its works fine